# How to load data from xml to dhtmlxScheduler

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

I am trying to load data from xml to dhtmlxScheduler

My code is:

```
function init()
{ 
  scheduler.locale.labels.timeline_tab = "Timeline";
 scheduler.locale.labels.section_custom="Section";
 scheduler.config.details_on_create=true;              
 scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick=true;
 scheduler.config.xml_date="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
 scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(2011,4,24),"timeline");
 scheduler.load("data.xml","xml");
}
```

Comment: please provide the solution as soon as possible..